# What is git status alternative for ! svn status result

Tags: git, svn

I am modifying a script which checks svn status for following result code: !

In the documentation I can see that ! corresponds to following description:

> Item is missing (e.g., you moved or deleted it without using svn). This also indicates that a directory is incomplete (a checkout or update was interrupted).

Example SVN result:

```
svn status
! trunk/script/test.txt
```

Can someone tell what is the git result alternative for !. I have checked git documentation but I am not sure if svn ! corresponds to D.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN and Git work a bit differently in this regard. The rough Git equivalent is deleted from the working directory, but not staged.

```
$ rm this 
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    this

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

You can get a short version with `git status -s` in which case it's a D in the second column.

```
$ git status -s
 D this
```

Git has a "staging area" which can be thought of as a place to build up a new commit. You make changes to your working directory (ie. the files on disk) and then "stage" them with `git add` and `git rm`. Then `git commit` commits what is staged.

Git is ok with you adding, deleting, and changing files outside Git. It will not commit them unless explicitly staged.

```
$ git rm this 
rm 'this'
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    this
```

And the short version is a D in the first column.

```
$ git status -s
D  this
```

See [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) for more.

---

In contrast SVN does not have a staging area; what is changed on disk is what is committed. Thus deleting a tracked file without telling SVN is abnormal; it's possible you did not mean to delete the file. And SVN commits are much harder to revise and undo than in Git.

Comment: so if in my code I have function svnAdd "if result == ? then (run svn add file) else if result == ! then (svn rm file) then in gitAdd function i have to cover two D where D is on first column and second column?

Comment: @Kecaj First D means it's already been staged for deletion. You only need to do `git rm` for the second D. If your intent is to simply add/rm all changes use `git add -A`.